# cannot preview in this file - the request to open "com.apple.dt.CcodePreview" failed

Tags: xcode, swiftui-previews, xcode-previews

Xcode version 14.3.1
Minimum Deployments 16.4

The problem started when I moved the Xcode to Applications(previously it was in somewhere else).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things I have tried and worked for me.

- Cleaning Build Folder
- Restarting Xcode
- Restarting Macbook

Then Run following command in terminal.

```
xcrun simctl --set previews delete all
```

Open Xcode, Build the project.